# Ubuntu 19.10 freeze the sidebar and top-bar until restart

Tags: 19.10

Ever bad experience in ubuntu 19.10, This the second time I'm facing this problem, The sidebar and top-bar are frozen which is not responding to me even when I hover over, click. It's solved when I restart my machine!

***I also tried this:***
`killall gnome-panel`

command not found, I see in this case

**Here is an image of top bar**

[image]

Comment: as a temporary remedy instead killall gnome panel try Alt+F2 dialogue box will open then type r and hit enter key

Comment: Wow, thanks for the helpful tip! at the first moment, I was assuming you destroyed my all work, but it's still safe to use!

Comment: Are you using extra Gnome Shell extensions? What is the graphical card and what graphics drivers do you use?

Comment: @UnKNOWn accurate

Answer (score 8):

The following steps worked for me:

> Press `Alt + F2` a box appears like the attached image.
>
> Input `r` and press Enter.

Tested in Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04. So, it should be just fine with 19 as well.

**Wayland:**

If you are using wayland or for any reason, the above method did not work try this:

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (login if needed) and

```
sudo systemctl stop gdm  #use lightgdm if you are on lightgdm
sudo systemctl start gdm #use lightgdm if you are on lightgdm
```

[image]

Comment: This works for me too. But what is it running behind the scenes? And why does the menu bar freeze?

Comment: This command reloads the interface. However, it doesn't work for Wayland.

Comment: @KTibow updated the answer